# Internet Recovery Mode's Terminal cannot run Disk Drill

Tags: terminal, command-line, imac, recovery, internet-recovery

[Disk Drill has an official tutorial](https://www.cleverfiles.com/help/disk-drill-recovery-mode.html) on how to run it directly from the Terminal on Internet Recovery Mode.

Basically, use `sh <(curl http://www.cleverfiles.com/­bootmode/boot.xml)` for Disk Drill 5, or `sh <(curl http://www.cleverfiles.com/­bootmode/boot4.xml)` for DiskDrill 4, and everything will work like magic.

The problem is: both commands fail to open DiskDrill after downloading it, on iMac running MacOS Catalina.

> dyld: dylkd cache load error: shared cache file open() failed
>
> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
>
> > Referenced from: /Volumes/DiskDrill/Disk Drill.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk Drill
> >
> > Reason: image not found
>
> /dev/fd/63: line 33: 684 Abort trap : 6 "$LaunchPath"

**How can I make Disk Drill run directly from Internet Recovery Mode without failing?**

**Or, at least, how can I discover why is it failing?**

Complete Terminal screen below:

[image: Complete Terminal screen]

Comment: It would be easier to install this onto a macOS installation that existed on a USB drive so you can move it from one Mac to another without having to do this overly complex setup that will only exist so long as the computer is on (it exists in RAM only)

Comment: You already know why it fails, the error message tells you.  Looks like  `libswiftCore.dylib` isn't available in Recovery Mode.  Maybe not in Catalina at all, if that's part of SwiftUI.

Comment: @Allan I'm just trying to avoid to ask another department to lend me a 32GB+ external memory, to install macOS on it (I never installed it before), to maybe not have any success in what I'll try to do.

Comment: For the sake of your sanity, use a personal one, and then requisition one later.   If they ask, say it got mixed up in your pocket.